# Custom Articles page only showing a limited number of posts per page

Tags: posts, themes, page-template, get-posts

I have been developing my own theme for my website over at http://haydenbjyoung.co.uk called FluX, and if you click on the 'Articles' link in the navbar, it only shows 5 articles, out of around 20 I think. I have no limit on post count on the custom template I made, and here's the template code.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Posts List */ get_header();?>
<h1 id="page_title">Stuff I've Written</h1>
<div id="posts_wrapper" class="skinny_wrapper">
  <?php global $post;

  $myposts = get_posts(array('post_type'=>'post'));
  foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <div class="post">
      <p class="date"><?php the_date(); ?></p>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
      <hr>
    </div>
  <?php endforeach;
  wp_reset_postdata();?>
</div>
<?php get_footer();  ?>
```

This is incredibly annoying. I tried limiting my posts to 20 to see if it showed more posts but it changed nothing. I don't want to be stuck in a scenario where potential readers only get to see 5 posts.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post limit is controlled in the admin panel, at `Settings > Reading`. There you can set the limit for how many posts should be shown in a query. However, the default post count for `get_posts()` is 5.

If you would like to query unlimited posts (regardless of performance issues), you can either create your own instance of `WP_Query()` or use the `pre_get_posts` filter to do so.

Using `WP_Query()` is pretty straight forward, and all you have to do is to pass `-1` to the query. You can do the same with [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) :

```
$args = array (
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    // Rest of the arguments here
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Now you can use a simple `while()` loop to output your content.

Comment: Would I just put this above the loop?

Comment: If you don't want to change your code's structure, just add `'posts_per_page' => -1,` to your `get_posts()` array, so it will become: `get_posts(array('post_type'=>'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1))`

Comment: Ah, unfortunately it still shows only 5.

Comment: You could try and use `numberposts` instead of `posts_per_page`. I personally never use `get_posts()`, so in this case this might be the issue.

Comment: Actually, after having implemented that and waiting a while, it worked. Thanks for the quick solution Jack :D